# Is .jsn the same as .json?

Tags: json

probably a dumb question, but I have a .jsn file that I'm supposed to strip away some unnecessary info from in python and I wanted to make sure .json and .jsn are the same before I proceed. From what I can tell, they are but just wanted to check. Thanks!

Comment: What's in a name? That which we call `json`, by any other name would parse just as fine.

Comment: The file extension means nothing if we can't see the contents of a file.  Invalid JSON could exist in a `.json` or `.jsn` file, and I could create a valid JSON file with a `.whatever` extension.

Comment: The file name means nothing at all, it might just affect what format some programs assume it is - open the file in a text editor and see what the file looks like, or ask/find out what format it uses.

Answer (score 1):

[JavaScript Object Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) i.e. JSON filenames use the extension .json. 
There is a .jsn file format attributed to [Shield Now Shield File (JetSoft Corporation)](https://www.file-extension.org/extensions/jsn) However there is no known link to a real company or file format. In all likely hood it is a simple spelling error. Looking at the format of the file will clearly answer the difference.